# Get keys of json and use to print values in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, key

I trying to get all keys and use them to access values of that keys, depends of user...

i have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('underscore');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('ENG.json', 'utf8'));
var lang = process.argv.slice(2);
var keys = _.keys(obj);
console.log(obj.keys[0].text1);
```

Help me please.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I need get a  values using keys variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this way?

```
keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

By the way, no need for underscore. Use `Object.keys(obj)`.

And you can easily require your json this way:

```
// most probably './ENG.json';
const obj = require('ENG.json');
```